# Reference of explanation of this result about Fourier transforms in euclidean space

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, vector-analysis

[The paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103941230) says that since $$u = - \nabla \times (\Delta^{-1} \omega)$$ "The Fourier transforms of $\nabla u$ and $\omega$ satisfy $(\nabla u)^{\text{^}}(\xi) = S(\xi)\hat\omega(\xi)$ where $S$ is a matrix which is bounded independent of $\xi$".

Does anyone recognize this theorem? Where could I find a proof for it?

Thanks for any light into this.

---

As for the meaning of $\Delta^{-1} \omega$, I think it is to choose some $f$ satisfying $\Delta f = \omega$ (even though this is not unique). Further it is a [correction of the typo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67814/inverse-of-the-curl) to write $\Delta$ instead of $\nabla$ as they did in the paper.